# What does "I will be back" mean in Shingeki no Bahamut?

Tags: shingeki-no-bahamut

At the end of the series, one of the characters said "I will be back," then the credits started.  Was that just a cool way to end the show or was that saying that there might/will be another season?

Comment: i haven't seen the Shingeki no Bahamut and can tell if it does match but it sounds like Arnold Schwarzenegger's signature line from *The Terminator*. in the Movie Schwarzenegger says this line but he actually never does come back to the person he says this too (if i recall right it was when he steals a biker's clothes and bike after arriving from the future). it's normally used as a cool line but if i rembered it right it could be a sign that there isn't going to be another anime season since Schwarzenegger while he said he'll be back to the biker never did come back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no green-lit at the moment for a sequel of Shingeki no Bahamut: Genesis. It's based on a card battle game for iOS and Android, so there's an endless stretch of coverage to adapt here.

The best we could assume is that it's "prophetic" for anything Shingeki no Bahamut-related since it is peculiar enough there are no *explicit* green-lit announcements yet. Anime usually do make the green-lit announcement after the series ended with a hint for a sequel. I take it they meant for something coming, but that's the best everyone (I've searched around) can count on. It could be a sequel, a spin-off (since it's wrapped up), movie, or OVA.

I'm confident, however, that in no way would they be making a senseless "I'll be back" hint without actually following up anything. Not once, in the hundreds of anime I've watched, would that happen. They could, however, announce a termination of whatever project they originally intended to continue the Bahamut hype.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is this is a tool used by the animators to ensure a connection whether (or not) they'd still get a second season. I see this in many series, they almost always put a cliffhanger or at least a promise of a next season just in case the show becomes successful enough to earn its season 2. fingers crossed for Shingeki no Bahamut: Season 2.